# Regex to capture this field?

Tags: regex

I would like to extract the the parameter name corresponding to the value 123.

For both these strings

```
[param1=456&param2=123]
[param2=123&param1=456]
```

I would like to find this value

```
param2
```

This regex works for the first line, but not for the second

```
&([\S]*)123
```

This regex works for the second line, but not for the first

```
[&|\[]([\S]*)123
```

Comment: Try `(\w*)(?:=123)`

Comment: @pkpkpk thanks! are `&` and `[` word separators?

Comment: If `123` is static, try [`[&[]([^\s=]*)=123`](https://regex101.com/r/56Fgnd/2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex will look for the name that is matched with 123

```
(\w+)(?:=123)[&\]]
```

- `\w+` is matching one or more alphanumeric characters,
- `(?:...)` is for a non capturing group so that you don't get the '=123' part
- `=123` is looking for the equality with the value you want
- `[&\]]` is looking to match a ']' or '&' right after '=123'

  - If the square brackets are not part of your string, then you could look for the end of the string instead with `[&$]`

Comment: `(\w+)(?:=123)` and `(\w+)=123` are equivalent. Note that `\w` won't match non-word chars, like `-`.

Comment: Why are you matching `]` and `&` ?

Comment: @ab11 Yes, this would work as well, and it actually a simpler solution

Comment: @pkpkpk Because without that it would match with 'param1=1234'. I am assuming that the strings contain the square brackets

Comment: @JacobBoertjes good point about `1234`, i hadn't considered that